# OpenGL MatrixModes

Tags: opengl, matrix

I can't really understand what these modes are doing.

I see you set 
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

before you draw vertices, but what does that actually mean? What is it doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenGL there are two main matrix modes (there are two others, but you probably don't need to be concerned with them), they are `GL_MODELVIEW` and `GL_PROJECTION`. Together they define much of how opengl transforms the vertices you put in into the visuals you get out. When you have called `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` most recently, you will be altering how your points will be shifted around in space, you can cause all of your points to be translated with `glTranslatef`, rotated with `glRotatef` and so on. When you have called `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)` you will be altering how your points get projected onto the screen. This is the mode you want to be in to call things like `gluPerspective` or `glOrtho`.

It is common to switch to projection mode before each major drawing step (main scene, GUI, etc) set up the projection matrices, then switch to modelview until the next one. This way, you can leave your projection unaltered while you change around the transformations of the scene by moving the camera, altering positions of objects, etc.

Comment: Actually it's good practice to set the projection at the begin of each frame iteration, too. If you're drawing HUDs, minimaps, or other elements which require some different projection you'll do that anyway.

Comment: Absolutely. My explanation was assuming a simple, single scene, no frills attached program, I will adjust my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

When you call glMatrixMode(), you set the matrix for the transformations that follow.

You will usually want to use GL_PROJECTION matrix for storing projection transformation (so calling glOrtho/glFrustum after changing to this matrix, and GL_MODELVIEW for positioning and rotating objects glRotate/glTranslate.

By separating these matrices, you can always zero the modelview matrix and don't have to compute the projection matrix again - typically the second will remain constant while displaying all objects.

example:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity(); //now we zero only the projection matrix
glOrtho(0,width,0,height,-1,1);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

// now you can use glTranslate and glRotate for positioning objects
// and then call glLoadIdentity() again to return to origin, still preserving your projection
```

I would also look at [The Red Book](http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter03.html) or tutorials on opengl.org, as they fully cover this topic.